# java keytool generated keystore missing PrivateKeyEntry

Tags: openssl, keytool

I've generated a keystore using java keytool. Then generated a CSR file using OpenSSL, which I sent to our CA. I've imported the 3 CERTs our CA sent us, but now my PrivteKeyEntry is missing from the keystore.

Any ideas on what might have caused this ?
Or, how to get the PrivateKeyEntry back ?

I'd really like to avoid another pass with the CA.

--Lyndon

Comment: _Exactly_ how did you generate the keystore? Did you use `keytool -genkeypair` (or the synonym `-genkey`)? OpenSSL can only generate a CSR from a privatekey/keypair stored in an OpenSSL-format PEM file (either 'legacy' or PKCS8), not any kind of Java keystore.

Comment: I used `keytool -genkeypair` to generate the keystore. And `keytool -certreq` to generate the CSR. Sorry about the misinformation about OpenSSL . OpenSSL was used to check the CSR information...